# Soap Response via Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, wsdl

When passing in a Soap Request through Java, my request appears to go through fine. However, for part of the response, I get the following:

```
A CXmlApiException was raised in native code : error 2 : scxmlapi(2) - No method supplied
```

When I try to add a WSDL file through the SoapUI plugin, I get this error:

```
Error loading [http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime
```

I think the above errors are related to each other. When I use the the SoapUI stand-alone application, I can connect to the WSDL without any errors and make requests. This makes me think that there is a configuration error within my eclipse settings.

Comment: Are you running it behind a proxy server?

Comment: I am not entirely sure, assuming I am, how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Your WSLD file is local ?

Comment: I'm calling a URL to retrieve it.

Comment: I believe you have to define proxy settings in the SoapUI plugin global preferences. There are settings there for host, port, username and password (for the proxy auth).

Comment: I never set any proxy settings in the standalone Soap UI application though? Why would the plugin within Eclipse be any different?